# Custom Item Url Builder

Tags: urls

Im trying to implement a custom Url Builder with Sitecore 9.3.I can't seem to figure out how to patch it. I made a custom url builder that implements BaseUrlBuilder but when I try to patch it in I get:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Transform.Foundation.ItemResolution.CustomItemUrlBuilder' to type 'Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder'.
```

Here is the current state of my patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <links>
        <itemUrlBuilder type="MySolution.Foundation.ItemResolution.CustomItemUrlBuilder,MySolution" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel']">
            <param type="Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions, Sitecore.Kernel" desc="defaultOptions">
                <alwaysIncludeServerUrl ref="links/urlBuilder/alwaysIncludeServerUrl"/>
                <languageEmbedding ref="links/urlBuilder/languageEmbedding"/>
                <languageLocation ref="links/urlBuilder/languageLocation"/>
                <lowercaseUrls ref="links/urlBuilder/lowercaseUrls"/>
                <encodeNames ref="links/urlBuilder/encodeNames"/>
                <useDisplayName ref="links/urlBuilder/useDisplayName"/>
                <addAspxExtension>false</addAspxExtension>
                <siteResolving>true</siteResolving>
                <shortenUrls>true</shortenUrls>
            </param>
        </itemUrlBuilder>
    </links>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Try inheriting from `Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder` and override the `Build(item, options)` method. BaseUrlBuilder doesn't appear to be registered in Services Config so this still does not appear to be using the IOC container.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? That was it.

Comment: Thanks, answer added, and updated - `BuildUrl()` would be probably a better method to override just for the custom link generation part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update in Sitecore 9.3 adds the new `itemUrlBuilder` configuration to control how item and media URLs are built. Unfortunately, this in not wired into the IoC container ([unlike the LinkManager itself](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/09/22/switching-link-manager/) for example). The [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/build-item-and-media-urls.html) states:

> The default Sitecore implementation of the `BaseLinkManager` class uses the `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` class. The `LinkProvider` class uses the `ItemUrlBuilder` class to generate item URLs.

If you take a look at the default implementation of the `LinkProvider` class you will see that the `Initialize` method uses the Sitecore Config Factory to create the itemUrlBuilder object, which is of type `ItemUrlBuilder` (and not of type `BaseUrlBuilder`)

Since the `sitecore/links/itemUrlBuilder` is indirectly called via the `LinkProvider`, you should instead inherit from `Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder` and override the `BuildUrl(item, options)` method.

```
public class CustomItemUrlBuilder : Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilder
{
    public override string BuildUrl(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
    {
        if (true) {
            // my custom url builder code
        } else {
            return base.BuildUrl(item, options);
        }
    }
}
```